# Getting NullReferenceException on Microsoft.windows.controls.MessageBox vertical scrollbar click

Tags: c#

Getting NullReferenceException on Microsoft.windows.controls.MessageBox when i click the arrow(up or down) in the vertical scrollbar

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();

errors = selectedJob.ValidationErrors;
if (errors != null && errors.Count() > 0)
{
    var msg = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,  errors);                                
    MessageBoxResult result =  Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox.Show(msg, title, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Any suggesstions would be helpful, I can't seem to figure out whats wrong here. Thanks in advance

Comment: which line do you hit nullref error on ? its a very generic error hence provide as much information as possible. thanks.

Comment: Is this inside the event method for the up/down errors?  And what line of your code is it throwing an exception?  And where are you creating/initializing `title`?

Comment: MessageBoxResult result =  Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox.Show(msg, title, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Error);
}

Comment: string title = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Missing fields in Job - ", _jobRepository.selectedJob.jobData.JobFileIO.JobName);

Comment: MessageBox.show is what is throwing the message

Comment: could you pease post the full message of the exception? seems to be a verry strange case...

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new empty list, but then assigning that object to selectedJob.ValidationErrors.
Did you mean to use `errors.AddRange(selectedJob.ValidationErrors);` ?

(btw, you should use `errors.Any()` instead of `errors.Count() > 0`)

And does using `title ?? String.Empty` not throw the exception?

Comment: I tried errors.AddRange(selectedJob.ValidationErrors) but that didn't fix the issue. Also "title" is not String.empty, it is getting filled in with some static text. See my comment above for details on the "title"